# Android Studio cannot resolve 3rd party dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

With the newer versions of Android Studio it has been advertised that you can add compile statements to the build.gradle file for 3rd party libraries that are available on Maven Central and Android Studio should be able to automatically download the appropriate dependencies. However I haven't been able to get the Gradle Sync to successfully complete when I try to add one of these libraries. Here is the build.gradle file for the project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsbysynapps.helloname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'

}
```

Here is the build.gradle for the module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Here is the error given out by Gradle

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5.
     Required by:
         HelloName:app:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

I've been having the same issue for any 3rd party library I've tried to add. This is also a brand new project created in Android Studio 1.1.0 and offline mode is disabled. Any ideas for what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried adding the repositories to your module gradle file as well?

Comment: @Solarnum Yes I have tried that and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Does it compile if you only include the support library dependency?

Comment: @stkent Yes it does. It is only when I include 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you manage to solve it?